# How to calculate number of samples from length of audio file?

Tags: ios, audio, sampling

Given an audio file of duration say 10s, how do I find out the no of samples betweeen 2s and 8s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if it's LPCM (e.g. not compressed), then use the sample rate.

in pseudocode:

```
double sampleRate = audioFile.getSampleRate();
// you may also need to account for channel count here
size_t sampleCount = sampleRate * (8-2);
```

-- where `(8-2)` represents "betweeen 2s and 8s"

Comment: sometimes you'll have to know the number of samples for all channels. for example, if you're performing interleaved rendering or utilizing a backing buffer to reduce file i/o. that's as easy as: `size_t sampleCount = sampleRate * (8-2) * audioFile.getChannelCount();`

Comment: Thank you! what exactly is a backing buffer to reduce file i/o..sorry but i'm new to audio..also please check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896472/obtain-sample-frame-offset-corresponding-to-certain-time-in-audio-file-iphone         for a related question

Comment: you're welcome. a backing buffer is a term for an intermediate or secondary audio sample buffer (array) which is stored in memory. example: you would use one if you are processing audio out of place or to reduce disk i/o. before you ask ;) - 'processing out of place' is the term used to render (e.g. filter, or apply an effect) to a buffer other than the input buffer. overwriting the input data with processed sample data is called processing in place. if you're recording audio, you'll want to write more than 64 samples per write request, you'd use a larger memory buffer (cont)

Comment: and write 2MB once the buffer fills. otherwise, the writes to disk will be frequent and comparably slow (unless the apis you're using to write already optimized that aspect for you and employ a buffer).

Comment: Okay. Thanks a ton again! :) 64 samples(each 8 bit) would make 512 bits. What is the significance of 2MB? I understood that only after the whole 2MB buffer fills, you write to disk.Regarding your previous comment,  utilizing a backing buffer to reduce file i/o means that we consider all the channels simultaneously and then write to disk instead of each channel separately. Have I understood it correctly?

Comment: please check the above link. I'm kinda stuck in that question.

Comment: you're welcome. 2MB: no significance, other than a better size to write. since this is tagged iphone, i chose a small amount of memory. most (but not all) file formats put all channels in one file. if you had a split stereo file (separate L+R), then you'd just use 2 separate buffers. but yes, what you've described is the common case for multichannel files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the duration property of the audio player for that purpose..

The duration property gives the duration of the current object of audio player(i.e the file that is currently being played)

So then you can supply all the audio files to the player one by one and check their durations and perform the required operations...

Cheers