# obtain sample frame offset corresponding to certain time in audio file-iPhone

Tags: audio, frames, sampling

Given an audio file of duration 10s, if I want to seek to 2s, how do I obtain the sample frame offset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it's LPCM (e.g. not compressed), then use the sample rate.

in pseudocode:

```
double sampleRate = audioFile.getSampleRate();
size_t offsetInSeconds = 2;
size_t sampleToRead = sampleRate * offsetInSeconds * audioFile.getChannelCount();
AudioSample sample = audioFile.getSampleAt(sampleToRead);
```